# Coordinator Layout cuts off screen from bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Here I'm hiding and showing `TabLayout` using `CollapsingToolbarLayout` inside `CoordinatorLayout` but it everytime cuts mobile device screen and shows of black color at bottom as

[image: Cutting Part]

And I'm following this code for it. But its still getting space from bottom without any margin.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/tab_green"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainTabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="58dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                app:tabBackground="@drawable/selector_tab"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/green"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                app:tabMaxWidth="72dp"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
                app:tabPaddingStart="0dp" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/btn_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/transparent2">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_black"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/black_light"></View>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view_black"
                android:background="@color/date_color"></View>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/tap_icon"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <com.cws.widget.NonSiwpablePager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_web"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/home"
        android:visibility="gone"></ImageView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/close_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="@string/got_it"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textSize="@dimen/et_tSize_big"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what are you trying but just set this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/tabanim_maincontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabanim_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

            <!-- View that will be hidden when video goes fullscreen -->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/nonVideoLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white">

                // your view

            </RelativeLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>


        /***
        Here You can add custom layout
        **/


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/black"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/black" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: `I don't know what are you trying` thats why I posted code.

Comment: Hahaha  the above code is for what you want just try it. :D

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this way-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/id_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/tab_green"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/mainTabLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="58dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    app:tabBackground="@drawable/selector_tab"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/green"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                    app:tabMaxWidth="72dp"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable"
                    app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
                    app:tabPaddingStart="0dp" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/btn_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/transparent2">

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view_black"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/black_light"></View>

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/view_black"
                    android:background="@color/date_color"></View>

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/view"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/tap_icon"
                    android:visibility="visible"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <com.cws.widget.NonSiwpablePager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                 />        
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_web"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/web_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/home"
            android:visibility="gone"></ImageView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/close_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="@string/got_it"
            android:textColor="@color/green"
            android:textSize="@dimen/et_tSize_big"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I have done it before also, still i tried again as you said but it dint change anything.

Comment: You have to set this behavior to only relative layout.
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
This behaviour must be Once in an xml file.